# Is it possible to compare files using Plastic SCM Command Line 'cm diff' function?

Tags: plasticscm

I'd like to compare two files at particular changesets to see if they are identical or not.

Something like:

```
>> cm diff rev:Folder\MyFile.py#cs:5 rev:Folder\MyFile.py#cs:10
<< True
```

I'm getting an error (can't find revision of file I specify) and I think I might not be using diff as it's intended. I've worked around my confusion by using getfile on the particular file and changesets I'm comparing and using a python library file compare.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plastic SCM default diff tool will open a GUI showing you the file differences.
But you can manually configure a different one (eg. diff.exe) manually editing the "/home/user/.plastic/client.conf" or using the Plastic SCM GUI:

```
<DiffToolData>
      <FileType>enTextFile</FileType>
      <FileExtensions>*</FileExtensions>
      <Tools>
        <string>diff.exe @sourcefile @destinationfile</string>
      </Tools>
</DiffToolData>
```

This way, you can run diffs through the command line and based on the output, determine if the files are identical or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cm patch` command

reference : https://blog.plasticscm.com/2018/11/unified-diff-of-branch.html